# Of the 60 ppl who went to a cash register 10 had blond hair and 15 had black hair, and 35 had red hair.

Tags: probability

Determine the probability the next person has black hair.

p (black hair) = 15/60 = 1/4

is this okay answer?

Comment: It is the most reasonable answer given the information.

Comment: I agree. If this is the complete problem, then you are right.

Comment: As a side note, you should not put the majority of your question in the title *only*.

Answer (score 1):

This is the maximum likelihood answer.

On the other hand, compare:

> Out of 1 ppl who went to the cash register 1 was named John Doe. Determine the probability that the next person is also named John Doe.

Answering $p=1$ here doesn't feel right, does it?
The problem is also in th eoriginal question that one person earlier the answer would have been either $\frac{15}{59}$ or $\frac{14}{59}$ by the same reasoning. Since we cannot have $p=\frac14\land p=\frac{15}{59}$ nor $p=\frac14\land p=\frac{14}{59}$ this casts a serious doubt on the method.

First of all, we should add a lot of hidden assumptions, such as:

- There is a probability $p$ such that the hair colour of the $n$th person at the cash register is black with probability $p$ and these events are independent for different $n$.
- A priori all values $p\in[0,1]$ are equally likely

Then we can conclude that a value of $p$ that *significantly* deviates from $\frac14$ would make the actually observed event (15 out of 60 random people have black hair) highly unlikely and would justify with some confidence us rejecting the hypothesis that $p$ has such a value. This is what is actually behind the guess that assuming $p=\frac14$ is reasonable. A better answer would specify an interval for $p$ and a level of significance.

Answer (score 0):

Since the probability is measured by the number of desired outcomes over the total number of outcomes, it seems you are right.